# How to allow a user to see a subset of a table or view

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I have a view in a private schema with several lets say company_id's. For a special use case I want to allow one company to see a subset of this table (for its own data). So I have create a role and a schema 'company_123' and I have created a view in this schema like

```
create view company_123.transactions_v as 
  select * from business.all_transactions_v
   where company_id = 123;
```

But unfortunately this view is empty as the user 'company_123' has no select rights on the original view. How could I achieve this requirement?

Comment: I think you're going to need to give this user read permissions on the original underlying table(s) beneath the view.  I doubt that Postgres security will let you hack around permissions by using views.

Comment: You need [Row Security Policies.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to grant SELECT permissions to the user on your table.

You can slice the visible [rows](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html) and [columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/sql-grant.html) to the user though and you should be able to solve your problem.